# Reactive Table: Hiding Observation and Edit in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming, reactive, dt

I'm creating a reactive shiny app, where I have to edit a data frame and save it. But in editing part, first I would like to hide all other observation except for the selected rows. I would like to edit it and again select few observation and edit it and save it again and so on.

I had created a sample data, Here I'm selecting a country and showing only that country observation. I would like to edit the prices column, It should update in overall data and I need to save it. Then later when I'm selecting a country, it will fetch data from edited data. And edit it save it automatically and go on

```r
rm(list = ls())


library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


#--------------------------------

df <- data.frame("country" =c("Russia", "China", "US", "India", "UK" )
                 , "tv_cost" = c(43, 67, 78, 56, 78 )
                 , "fridge_cost" = c(78, 45, 56, 78, 47)
                 , "microwave" = c(44, 23,31,29, 34)
                 )


#Shiny Dashboard

ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "green"
                    , dashboardHeader(title = "Edit Table")
                    , dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(menuItem("Edit Data", tabName = "tab_01" )
                                                   , menuItem("Output", tabName = "tab_02")
                                                   , menuItem("Input", tabName = "tab_03")
                                                   ))
                    , dashboardBody(tabItems(tabItem(tabName = "tab_01"
                                                     , selectInput(inputId = "countryid", label = "SELECT COUNTRY" , choices = df$country )
                                                     , DT::dataTableOutput("table1"))
                                             , tabItem(tabName = "tab_02", DT::dataTableOutput("table2"))
                                             , tabItem(tabName = "tab_03", DT::dataTableOutput("table3"))
                                             ))
                    )#dashboardpage ends here

server <- function(input, output, session){

  #Creating a blank Data frame to update every change 
  df_02 <- reactive(df_03 <-  NULL)


  #Showing Data table, for editing, "I'm filtering data here but I have to hide other observation "
  df_04 <- reactive(df %>% 
                      filter(country == input$countryid )) 


  output$table1 <-  renderDT({df_04()})

  # saving the edit data

  #Observing edited table 

  #updating it edited frame df_02

  #Rendering overall edited df. 
  output$table2 <- renderDT({df_02()})

  #input file
  output$table3 <- renderDT({df})



}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks in Advance